# Can't use Xam.Plugin.Media plugin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have android application that is built using Xamarin Forms. In order to use camera of the mobile, I install Xam.Plugin.Media plugin and follow exactly the instructions of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJYLrVNY2ak).

This is my code:

```
public async void TakePhotoAsAttachment(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "test.jpg"
            });

            if (file == null)
                return;

            await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

            image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                return stream;
            });
        }
```

However, when executing this code:

```
        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Sample",
            Name = "test.jpg"
        });
```

I get this error:

> {Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   md55b01af31820394fbfb172542d1258596.MediaPickerActivity --->
>   Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "md55b01af31820394fbfb172542d1258596.MediaPickerActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.companyname.EClinicForDoctor-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.EClinicForDoctor-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.companyname.EClinicForDoctor-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in
>   <54816278eed9488eb28d3597fecd78f8>:0    at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass,
>   System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in
>   :0    at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass,
>   System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00017] in
>   :0    at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x0003d]
>   in :0    at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.Type type) [0x00084] in
>   :0    at Java.Lang.Class.FromType
>   (System.Type type) [0x00022] in :0
>   at Android.Content.Intent..ctor (Android.Content.Context
>   packageContext, System.Type type) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   Plugin.Media.MediaImplementation.CreateMediaIntent (System.Int32 id,
>   System.String type, System.String action,
>   Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreMediaOptions options, System.Boolean
>   tasked) [0x00000] in
>   C:\projects\mediaplugin\src\Media.Plugin.Android\MediaImplementation.cs:411
>   at Plugin.Media.MediaImplementation.TakeMediaAsync (System.String
>   type, System.String action,
>   Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreMediaOptions options) [0x00044] in
>   C:\projects\mediaplugin\src\Media.Plugin.Android\MediaImplementation.cs:470
>   at Plugin.Media.MediaImplementation+d__17.MoveNext ()
>   [0x000ab] in
>   C:\projects\mediaplugin\src\Media.Plugin.Android\MediaImplementation.cs:153
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0    at
>   EClinicForDoctor.Pages.VisitsPage+d__17.MoveNext
>   () [0x00175] in E:\Doctor Project\Mobile
>   Applications\v1\4\EClinicForDoctor\EClinicForDoctor\EClinicForDoctor\Pages\VisitsPage.xaml.cs:235
>   --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace --- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   md55b01af31820394fbfb172542d1258596.MediaPickerActivity   at
>   java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)   at
>   md5270abb39e60627f0f200893b490a1ade.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.n_onClick(Native
>   Method)   at
>   md5270abb39e60627f0f200893b490a1ade.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.onClick(ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.java:30)
>     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)   at
>   android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "md55b01af31820394fbfb172542d1258596.MediaPickerActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.companyname.EClinicForDoctor-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.EClinicForDoctor-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.companyname.EClinicForDoctor-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]    at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)     ... 14 more
>     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   md55b01af31820394fbfb172542d1258596.MediaPickerActivity       at
>   java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)       at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)         at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)         at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)         ... 15 more
>     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack trace available }

Then I read the instructions of the plugin from [github](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) which it was somehow similar to the instructions of the video and the same error occur. How can solve this problem?

Comment: is it working fine on iOS?

Comment: I run it only on Android only. I do't have MAC computer.

Comment: have you install plugin in portable and android both? also try to delete bin obj folder of each project

Comment: Thanks bro. Its worked after deleting the bin and obj folder. Write your comment as answer to make it true. But Can you tell me why this is happened  ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try to delete the bin obj folder of your project.**

Your compile code and NuGet sits in obj, bin folder. Sometimes when you add any new NuGet it doesn't go in obj, bin folder. It only use earlier compiled NuGet as cache from bin and obj. Deleting all bin, obj force compiler to create new bin obj folder and recompile the solution. It is better idea to delete bin, obj whenever you add any new NuGet in solution.